# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6: Reading Cache in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an application with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

In my base-viewmodel, I have to access the application- and the session-cache.

Of course I could pass the cache-objects from my controller to the viewmodel to the base-viewmodel, but this seems a bit complicated.

Whats the way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first! Nobody will understand or even bother to answer your question

Comment: Thanks for linking the article. I read it but I am struggling with understand whats wrong about the question. If you could give me more precice information, I would be able to reformulate it. (This is a really honest comment, I'm trying to make it right). Thanks again

Comment: Explan what it is you're trying to achieve. Share the code you tried and explain where you're in doubt

Comment: Sorry for that. Since it's an architectural question, I didn't think code is required. I will try to do better next time, thanks! Also, I don't know what code I should add, since my question is how to access the cache from a viewmodel. But I will try =)

Comment: Asp.Net 5 (now ASP.Net Core) has the feature to inject dependencies right into the view. That doesn't mean it is a good idea. Under some circumstances (global configuration values, maybe) it is useful. I would ask following questions: Is it something, that only ever is useful in rendering the view or is it some data, that should better be controlled by the controller for future changes/manipulations. In the first case you could use the answer from Danny, otherwise put it in the controller. If it is a separate section in your view, the new "View Components" could also solve your problem nicely.

Comment: @flynn Yeah, there is also the cache taghelper and the responsecache attribute. For every scenario another solution.

Comment: @flynn "That doesn't mean it is a good idea." is a very good concern! Thanks for pointing it out. In my specific case, I think it's the most practical way to go - but I am sure in most cases it's not the best thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I gather you would want to request an instance of IMemoryCache via Dependency Injection. You can read how to do this here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/memory.html